# Do I need an domain name for a website?

Tags: dns, ip

I want to create a website for myself that no one else will use at the moment.

Do I need to get a domain name to be able to access the website remotely or can I just use the host IP address when I want to go on it?

Comment: DNS is only required to convert a convenient name to an IP address. You might want to check your router to see if it ties into a free dynamic IP service. I know the high end Asus routers will register an .asuscomm.com name for you, but I'm not sure of other brands.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're looking to do. For example, Ruby on Rails and Sinatra languages can be locally hosted. So you can basically create the website without ever having to 'push' it to a domain. You'll definitely need a domain if you want to access it remotely - the domain name is basically a mask for an IP address anyway, so they're really somewhat the same.

You can also have basic JavaScript (JS) /HTML/CSS sites locally hosted as well. So you don't really need a domain, until you want people to actually start showing up to it remotely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that does help thanks, do you know why you need a domain name to remotely access it as if it is just a mask for the IP then can't you just skip the domain and search for your website using the IP only and save having to buy a domain

Comment: @TristanWarren - Maybe think of it like this - when you buy a domain, you're buying an IP address on a server somewhere. Since people can't remember IP addresses easily, they can be assigned to letters like a domain. See for yourself by typing in Google.com's IP address in your web browser - http://74.125.20.106  You tend to hold the IP address and the domain name as separate things, but they're almost always attached b/c it's easy to assign a domain name to an IP and doing so doesn't take resources (like simply having an IP address).